# How can I restore data in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, database-restore, orientdb-2.1

I accidentally deleted admin account in the user table.

Is there a way I can restore it?

I don't have any backup data at the moment.

Any tips or comment will be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access via studio using server root password and recreate admin user in the security tab.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or you can use the console connecting via remote protocol using server root password.